# Image regression with unknown number of targets/labels

Tags: image, regression, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I have grey scale images with an **unknown frequency** of handwriten digits (0-9) on them.

I am trying a build machine learning model that determines:

1. The x,y coordinate for each digit.
2. The digit label (i.e. 0-9).

**Example**

(I couldn't upload the greyscale images, so suppose `.` denotes "black background", and the numbers represent themselves):

```
Image1:     Image2:     Image3:
7.......    .2......    ........
........    .....3..    ........
....1...    ........    ........
........    ....2...    ........
```

Thus, letting `f` denote my machine learning model/function we should have:

```
f(Image1) = [ label0:[], f(Image2) = [ label0:[], f(Image3) = [ label0:[],
              label1:[(x=4,y=2)],      label1:[],               label1:[],
              label2:[],               label2:[(x=1,y=0),       label2:[],
                                               (x=1,y=3)],      
              label3:[],               label3:[(x=5,y=1)],      label3:[],
              label4:[],               label4:[],               label4:[],
              label5:[],               label5:[],               label5:[],
              label6:[],               label6:[],               label6:[],
              label7:[(x=0,y=0)],      label7:[],               label7:[],
              label8:[],               label8:[],               label8:[],
              label9:[],               label9:[],               label9:[],
             ]
```

I'm attempting to apply deep learning methods using Keras to solve both problems at the same time, but I'm struggling to setup my labels as there are an unknown number of labels for each image.

Anyone have any ideas about how I could setup such a problem for deep learning?Should I break the problem into 2 stages (location then classification - but then the location problem still has an unknown number of labels)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can divide this problem to two parts.

In first part you should create a method for detecting if in the image is digit or not. For this purpose you can use method called "sliding windows" [(watch this video by Andrew Ng explaining this method)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nlMjSWnvglU). Assume you have image with size 200x200 and each digit has size around 20x20. You can create a window of size 20x20, and in each iteration window is moving right by 20 pixels (or less/more), if window reach right part of image, its moving back to left side, and 20 pixel down (or less/more). After each move of window you're cropping image, checking by using neural network if there's digit on cropped image. If there's digit, you're saving x, y coordinates of window and cropped image to images' array.

Second part should be easy, having digits you're passing them to neural network which determines digit's label.

So, you should train two neural networks - one for detecting if there's digit on image or not, and second for determining label of digit.

There's second way to find digits on image, you can train neural network which determines number of digits on image (it might be difficult), and then, by using [k-means](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_assumptions.html) (you should set number of clusters to number of digits you're got from NN) you can find positions of digits if they're not too close to each other. I did this in one project, and it worked, but you should have images with plain background and you have to create an array with pixels positions which have brightness exceeding some threshold.